# Using methods to select an object's property and assign it a value creates an error

Tags: javascript, object, methods, properties

I am trying to write a method that based on some value, returns a property that I'd like to define in another method. However, I am having a strange `'Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment'` error.

If I use a method to return a property of the object and I try to assign a new value to it, it spits out the error. But if I call the object.property and assign it a new value, it works.

Further, I run a test: the `object.property == object.method(value)` (which calls the property) returns true!

It seems like I am using the `=` correctly.

```
const test = () => {
    const y = 1; 
    const z = 2; 

    const mySelector = function(value) {
        if (value > 0) {
            return this.y;
        }
        else {
            return this.z;
        }
    }

    const definer = function (value){
        mySelector(value) = 9;
    }

    return {y, z, mySelector, definer}
}


let testInstance = test();

// this line spits out a an error: 
testInstance.definer(-1); // Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

testInstance.z = 9; // but this is ok

testInstance.z == testInstance.mySelector(-1) // true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mySelector(value) = 9` You can't make an assignment this way.

We can imagine this line as follows.

1. You give the `-1` argument to the `definer` function and call it.
2. We are now inside the definer function, and we are passing the value
   `-1`  to the `mySelector` function.
3. We are inside the `mySelector` function. `-1` is not greater than `0`. The else block runs and we return the `z` corresponding to the value `2` to the `definer` function.
4. And we are in the `definer` function again. The value `2` came from the
   `mySelector` function. We can now write `2` instead of `mySelector(value)`. 
   The resulting image is `2 = 9`. Yes, we found it! This is an "invalid left-hand side in assignment" error.

Maybe now it has made more sense what caused the error that popped up.

---

## EDIT

*"what's the best way to do so?"* It would not be correct to say that the best way is this or that. There is more than one way to get the result you want.

I will mention a few more points in response to your comment.

```
let testInstance = test()
```

The `test` function returns an object. and this object has four properties named "`y`, `z`, `mySelector`, `definer`" and values defined for these properties.

The `testIstance` variable now references this [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics).

```
testInstance.z = 9
```

In this line where you wrote, you access the `z` property of the `testInstance` object and change its value. Everything works fine here.

```
testInstance.z == testInstance.mySelector(-1)
```

But this line has a deeper information to know, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword.

I will not go into the details of the `this` keyword here. Therefore, you can understand better by reading and applying from the source I have given. But I will briefly explain why this line returns `true`.

First of all, let's not forget that we set the value of the `z` property of the `testInstance` object to `9` in the previous line of this line. (`testInstance.z = 9`)

Now we know that when we access the `z` property of the `testInstance` object on the left side of the equation, it will give us the value `9`. Let's simulate it,

`9 == testInstance.mySelector(-1)`

Now let's examine the right-hand side of the equation. We call the `mySelector` method of the `testInstance` object. This method returns `this.y` or `this.z` depending on the condition. And in our example the else block will work because of the `-1`. The main part starts here.

Simply, whenever you create a javascript object, the methods of this created object can access the object itself with the `this` keyword.
Here the keyword `this` points to our `testInstance` object.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#as_an_object_method)

> When a function is called as a method of an object, its this is set to the object the method is called on.

Let's continue where we left off, the else block is processed and `this.z` returns.

Since in our example we are calling the `mySelector` method of the `testInstance` object, the `this` keyword points to our `testInstance` object. And we previously set the value of the `z` property of the `testInstance` object to `9`. That's why it returns `9` from `this.z`.

And the result is `9 == 9`, true.

## A quick note about 'this'

**ES5 Function**

```
const test = () => {
  const mySelector = function(value) {
        console.log(this) // this -> points to the object itself
  }

  return { mySelector } 
}
```

**ES6 Arrow Function**

```
const test = () => {
  const mySelector = (value) => {
        console.log(this) // this -> points to the window object
  }

  return { mySelector } 
}
```

In your example, `mySelector` function is written with the es5 syntax, it points to the `testInstance` object itself. But if it was written in es6 syntax, `testInstance.z == testInstance.mySelector(-1)` would return false here. Because the `this` keyword would point to the `window` object, and since the window object has no `z` property, it returns `undefined`.

`9 == undefined`, false.

Final touch, a function's `this` keyword behaves a little differently in JavaScript compared to other languages. Researching and practicing this topic is an important step towards understanding the results.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thank you for your help! I do want to figure out what's the best way to make a function to call on this logic repeatedly. If I want to make a function that calls on a method for me to assign values, what's the best way to do so? For example, I would want to use the "mySelector" logic multiple times. However, the way I made the construction is faulty as you eloquently pointed out. I can write that logic in repeatedly for the times I would "call mySelector" but my code would get very long. Any suggestions?

Comment: @luckystrike I edited my answer after your comment, adding a few more points. I hope it helps. If anything else happens, let me know.